# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with where or if

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have quiz results from 3 separate quizs stored in 3 seperate tables that are exactly the same, so I have quiz_results_1, quiz_results_2 and quiz_results_3 in this structure:

username | quest1 | quest2 | quest3 | quest4 | quest5 | quest6 | quest7 | quest8 | quest9 | quest10 | complete

I would like to merge these tables into 1 table and include a quiz_id to identify which results are for which quiz:

quiz_id | username | quest1 | quest2 | quest3 | quest4 | quest5 | quest6 | quest7 | quest8 | quest9 | quest10 | complete

I can use this query to update the relevant table, with username as a primary key:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO quiz_results_1 (quest1,quest2,quest3,quest4,quest5,quest6,quest7,quest8,quest9,quest10,username‌​,complete) VALUES $queryData ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quest1=VALUES(quest1),quest2=VALUES(quest2),quest3=VALUES(quest3),quest4=VALUES(‌​quest4),quest5=VALUES(quest5),quest6=VALUES(quest6),quest7=VALUES(quest7),quest8=‌​VALUES(quest8),quest9=VALUES(quest9),quest10=VALUES(quest10),complete=VALUES(comp‌​lete)");
```

I would like to use only one table and insert if the row doesn't exist or update if the username and the quiz_id exist.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The only primary key is username - quiz_id is just an integer

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking exactly. Could you specify exactly what tables you have at the time (with a few example rows) and what you want to have afterwards (with some example rows)?

Answer (score 0):

Having 3 tables for the 3 quizzes is not a very good design.

So your choice to move into using one table only seems appropriate but you should change the Primary Key to `(quiz_id, username)` - and this will also solve the `UPDATE` statement problem.

Or, if you want to store different versions/histories of the quiz per user, change the Primary Key to: `(quiz_id, username, complete)`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but if I do this then it will only update if the username and quiz_id are unique. I really need it to insert or update when the username changes, but the quiz_id stays the same.

Comment: @tomp: You mean you want to keep `(username)` as the Primary Key, while adding `quiz_id` as a column in the new (and only one) table?

Comment: So, if a user has done 3 quizes, where will the results be stored? There will be only 1 row with his `username`.

Comment: Yes, so I can't use `(username)` as a primary key - which means I need to think about how to store the data more